# What is the promotional "card" size for iOS6 App Store listings?

Tags: layout, ios6, interface, app-store

I'm trying to figure out how to preview what my app would look like in the iOS6 App Store. Included is an example of "the card" that I'm talking about.

While I can eyeball the size of components, I'm looking for something more accurate.

- What is the precise pixel size of the white **rounded rectangle card** that is used to display the app? (It seems to be 312x336, but I may be wrong)
- What is the **corner radius** of hte card
- What is the **size of the screenshot** displayed with the card? (I'm calculating this as 180 high)
- What is the icon size?

The rest seems pretty straightforward - the label is up to two lines long, truncating at the end, and the developer name appears to use the new iOS6 constraints to be laid out just under the app name.

**Is there some place where I can learn what all these sizes used for this card are?**

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "promo card" on search results and iPhone 5:
-Icon 126x126px 
-Screenshot is 314x558px